# send values ​from the child component to the parent and sum the result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'm using useFieldArray from react-hook-form to replicate my requirements component, but I need to get the return value from the requirementValueCalc function and pass it to my form component. In it I want to sum the values ​​of each inserted field. Can someone help me?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAdYl.png)

My form - parent component:

```
const ThirdPage: ForwardRefRenderFunction<
  HTMLSelectElement,
  ThirdPageProps
> = ({
  formProps: {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    control,
    setValue,
    setFocus,
  },
  formData,
  secondPageData,
}) => {
  const {
    dealId,
    object,
    contractPeriod,
    paymentMethodId,
    dueDay,
    totalHours,
    totalValue,
  } = formData[0];

  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState<number>(0);
  const [requirements, setRequirements] = useState<RequerimentType[]>([]);

  const { append, remove, fields, insert } = useFieldArray({
    name: 'requirements',
    control,
  });

  const requirementOptions = requirements?.map(
    useCallback(
      (requirement) => {
        return {
          id: requirement.id,
          name: `${requirement.title} (${Math.floor(
            requirement.estimate / 8
          )} dias)`,
          value: requirement.title,
          effort: requirement.estimate,
          coefficient: requirement.coefficient,
        };
      },
      [requirements]
    )
  );

  const handleKeyPress = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
    if (
      (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) &&
      event.key === 'ArrowUp' &&
      currentIndex > 0
    ) {
      insert(currentIndex, {});
    }

    if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && event.key === 'ArrowDown') {
      insert(currentIndex + 1, {});
    }
    if (
      (event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) &&
      event.key === 'Backspace' &&
      currentIndex > 0
    ) {
      remove(currentIndex);

      setFocus(`requirements.${currentIndex - 1}.title`);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
    };
  }, [handleKeyPress]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAllRequirements = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await listAllRequirements();

        setRequirements(response.data.items);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.response.data);
      }
    };

    getAllRequirements();

    append({});
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className='flex flex-col divide-y divide-zinc-700 divide-opacity-25 px-6 last:border-0 sm:px-2'>
        <div className='flex flex-col'>
          <div className='flex flex-row items-center justify-between gap-10'>
            <Input
              placeholder='Id da oportunidade vem do RD'
              label='Id da oportunidade'
              withoutBorder
              error={errors.dealId}
              {...register('dealId')}
              defaultValue={dealId}
            />

            <Input
              placeholder='Objeto'
              label='Objeto'
              withoutBorder
              error={errors.object}
              {...register('object')}
              defaultValue={object}
            />
          </div>

          <div className='flex flex-row items-center justify-between gap-10 pt-6'>
            <Input
              placeholder='Período do contrato'
              label='Período do contrato'
              withoutBorder
              error={errors.contractPeriod}
              {...register('contractPeriod')}
              defaultValue={contractPeriod}
            />

            <Input
              placeholder='Método de pagamento'
              label='Método de pagamento'
              withoutBorder
              error={errors.paymentMethodId}
              {...register('paymentMethodId')}
              defaultValue={paymentMethodId}
              disabled
            />
          </div>

          <div className='flex items-center justify-between gap-10 pt-6'>
            <Input
              placeholder='Dia de vencimento da parcela'
              label='Dia de vencimento da parcela'
              type='number'
              withoutBorder
              error={errors.dueDay}
              {...register('dueDay')}
              defaultValue={dueDay}
            />
            <div className='flex w-full flex-row items-center justify-between gap-10'>
              <div className='flex w-full justify-end'>
                <input
                  label='Total de horas'
                  id='totalHours'
                  type='number'
                  hidden
                  error={errors.totalHours}
                  {...register('totalHours')}
                  defaultValue={totalHours}
                />
              </div>

              <div className='flex w-full flex-col items-start gap-2'>
                <input
                  id='totalValue'
                  hidden={true}
                  defaultValue={totalValue}
                  {...register('totalValue')}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr className='mt-8 border-dark-300 pt-5' />

          <div className='flex w-full justify-between'>
            <h1 className='font-bold text-primary-600'>Requisitos</h1>

            <Tooltip />
          </div>

          {fields.map((field, index) => (
            <Requirement
              fieldId={field.id}
              errors={errors}
              index={index}
              register={register}
              setCurrentIndex={setCurrentIndex}
              requirementOptions={requirementOptions}
              setValue={setValue}
              currentIndex={currentIndex}
              hourValue={secondPageData.hourValue}
            />
          ))}

          <div className='flex w-full justify-end'>
            <div className='flex-col'>
              <div className='flex justify-end'>
                <h6 className='py-2 text-white'>{`200 / horas`}</h6>
              </div>
              <div className='flex justify-end'>
                <Title size={'bold'}>{`R$ teste`}</Title>
              </div>
              <div className='flex justify-end'>
                <h6 className='py-2 text-white'>
                  <b>4 sprint</b> / ORÇADO
                </h6>
              </div>
              <div className='flex justify-end'>
                <h6 className='py-2 text-white'>
                  <b>{`test dias úteis`}</b> / CONTRATO
                </h6>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ThirdPage;
```

My requirement component - child component:

```
const Requirement = ({
  hourValue,
  fieldId,
  errors,
  index,
  register,
  setCurrentIndex,
  requirementOptions,
  setValue,
  currentIndex,
}: SelectProps) => {

  const [coefficient, setCoefficient] = useState<number>();
  const [effort, setEffort] = useState<number>();

  const requirementValueCalc = (effort: number, factor: number, hourValue: number) => {
    const result = effort * factor * hourValue;
    return result;
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div key={fieldId} className='flex flex-col gap-3'>
        <div className='flex flex-row items-center justify-start gap-10'>
          <div>
            <Input type={'checkbox'}></Input>
          </div>
          <div className='w-2/6'>
            <div>
              {errors.requirements?.[index].title?.message && (
                <span className='text-xs text-error-900'>
                  {errors.requirements?.[index].title?.message}
                </span>
              )}
            </div>

            <Input
              id='requirementTitle'
              placeholder='Título do requisito'
              withoutBorder
              {...register(`requirements.${index}.title`)}
              onFocus={() => setCurrentIndex(index)}
              className={classNames(
                errors.requirements
                  ? 'border-error-900 px-3 py-2 placeholder-error-900 focus:border-error-900 focus:ring-error-900'
                  : 'border-transparent px-3 py-2 placeholder-dark-300 focus:border-primary-500 focus:ring-0',
                'block w-full appearance-none rounded-md border',
                'bg-dark-900 text-white caret-primary-600',
                'focus:outline-none sm:text-sm'
              )}
            />
          </div>

          <div className='flex w-1/4 gap-3'>
            {requirementOptions.length > 0 && (
              <>
                <Select
                  handleSetValue={(value) =>
                    setValue(
                      `requirements.${index}.typeRequirementId`,
                      value.id,
                      setCoefficient(value.coefficient),
                      setEffort(value.effort),
                    )
                  }
                  options={requirementOptions}
                />
                <div className='flex ml-8 w-full gap-3'>
              <Title size={'bold'}>{`R$ ${requirementValueCalc(coefficient, effort, hourValue)}`}</Title>
            </div>
              </>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='mb-5 flex flex-col gap-2'>
          <div>
            {errors.requirements?.[index].description?.message && (
              <span className='text-xs text-error-900'>
                {errors.requirements?.[index].description?.message}
              </span>
            )}
          </div>

          <textarea
            id='description'
            rows={2}
            placeholder='Descrição do requisito'
            className={classNames(
              errors.requirements
                ? 'border-error-900 px-3 py-2 placeholder-error-900 focus:border-error-900 focus:ring-error-900'
                : 'border-transparent px-3 py-2 placeholder-dark-300 focus:border-primary-500 focus:ring-0',
              'block w-full appearance-none rounded-md border',
              'bg-dark-900 text-white caret-primary-600',
              'focus:outline-none sm:text-sm'
            )}
            {...register(`requirements.${index}.description`)}
          />
        </div>

        <hr className={currentIndex ? 'border-dark-300 pb-5' : 'invisible'} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export { Requirement };
```

I tried to solve it, taking the child's values ​​and sending them to the parent with a callback, but I'm not managing to keep the dynamic elements with their indexes.

Comment: what is  <> thats empty?

Comment: just a fragment to insert the content